# Oracle MAF 2.3.0 Jdeveloper 12.2.1 can't deploy applications

Tags: java, android, oracle, jdeveloper, oracle-maf

i'm developing an android app with MAF 2.3.0 in Jdeveloper 12.2.1 on a Ubuntu x64 OS and i have android SDK emulator running but everytime i want to deploy my apps i get an error :

```
[03:40:37 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[03:40:37 PM] Target platform is  (Android).
[03:40:37 PM] Beginning deployment of MAF application "MobileApp" to Android using profile "Android1".
[03:40:38 PM] Checking state of Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:40:41 PM] Started Android Debug Bridge server.
[03:40:41 PM] Verifying a single Android emulator is online and connected to the ADB server...
[03:40:42 PM] Cordova Plugman could not be found and needs to be installed.
[03:40:42 PM] This one-time installation may take a few minutes.
[03:40:42 PM] Installing Cordova Plugman...
[03:40:46 PM] Command-line executed: [/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/java, -jar, /home/hadi/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/maf-helper.jar, installTools, -tools, /home/hadi/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools]
[03:40:46 PM] Creating directory /home/hadi/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/plugman
[03:40:46 PM] Installing plugman ...
[03:40:46 PM] Error Code : INTERNAL_ERROR
[03:40:46 PM] /home/hadi/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/npm: 2: exec: /home/hadi/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/jdeveloper/jdev/extensions/oracle.maf/tools/node-linux-x86/bin/node: not found
[03:40:46 PM] oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[03:40:46 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.installTools(Unknown Source)
[03:40:46 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.MafHelperMain.main(Unknown Source)
[03:40:46 PM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[03:40:46 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.runProcess(Unknown Source)
[03:40:46 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.internal.utils.MafHelperInternalUtilities.executeCmd(Unknown Source)
[03:40:46 PM] ... 2 more
[03:40:46 PM] Caused by: oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException: java.lang.Exception
[03:40:46 PM] ... 4 more
[03:40:46 PM] Caused by: java.lang.Exception
[03:40:46 PM] at oracle.maf.mafhelper.api.MafHelperException.<init>(Unknown Source)
[03:40:46 PM] ... 4 more
[03:40:46 PM] Shutting down Android Debug Bridge server...
[03:40:46 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[03:40:47 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[03:40:47 PM] An error occurred installing plugman. (oracle.adfmf.framework.dt.deploy.common.deployers.plugins.PlugmanInstallerDeployer)
```

Comment: Does the user you run JDeveloper with has enough rights to read/write to the folders you see in your log? Seems like Installing plugman is failing, wich might be caused by insufficient rights.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tired all methods running jdev using sudo and other methods, but i also opened this discussion up in oracle forums and they replied that you can run and test oracle products on ubuntu but it's not the OS they support, so i moved on to windows, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Final support for MAF in JDeveloper is 12.2.1.3.0 . This is the last build version of JDeveloper support efficient MAF application deployment. So try this version of JDeveloper IDE.